# There are given $n$ points on plane. Prove that there are not more than $n$ pairs of vertices, distance between which is exactly $d$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, plane-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

$\textbf{Source:}$I found this question in aops[link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1900222p12987439)

As you can see in this link it doesn't mention any source either.

$\textbf{Question:}$There are given $n$ points on plane. Let $d$ be the biggest distance between any pair of vertices. Prove that there are not more than $n$ pairs of vertices, distance between which is exactly $d$

I tried to use induction.The base case is obvious.Assuming the result is true for n points,I tried to show that it also holds for $n+1$ points.Now,If I could show that there is one point which makes at most one pair with distance $d$, I would be done.So,assuming otherwise all points is in at least two pair whose distance is $d$.I could not progress any far.

I would appreciate some hint or solution.Thanks in advance

Comment: Wow! This is a hard one. Where did you find this?

Comment: @Yesit'sme A link to the original problem would be appropriate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this post does not contain the source of the contest problem, which is necessary to comply with our [contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy).

Comment: @KReiser I found the link and added it.I honestly didn't know about this policy.So,I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ denote the graph on the $n$ vertices, where two vertices share an edge if and only if the distance between them is $d$. Let $k$ denote the number of edges in $G$. We wish to show that $k\leq n$.

Let $G'$ denote the graph obtained by repeatedly removing all vertices $v\in G$ with $\deg v\leq1$, so that the number of edges removed is no greater than the number of vertices removed. Then it suffices to show that $k'\leq n'$, where $n'$ and $k'$ denote the numbers of vertices and edges of $G'$, respectively.

Suppose toward a contradiction that $\deg v\geq3$ for some $v\in G'$. The pairwise distance between the neighbours of $v$ is also at most $d$, and hence all neighbours of $v$ lie on a circular arc of radius $d$ centered at $v$ of at most $\tfrac\pi3$ radians. Let $w_1,w_2\in G'$ be the two neighbours of $v$ that are furthest apart, and $w\in G'$ any other neighbour of $v$. The following image clarifies the situation:

[image]

The four circles are centered at $v$, $w_1$, $w_2$ and $w$ and all have the same radius $d$. It follows that all other vertices of $G'$ are contained in the region shaded red. In particular the only vertex in $G'$ at distance $d$ from $w$ is $v$. But then in $G'$ we have $\deg w=1$, a contradiction. This shows that $\deg v=2$ for all $v\in G$ and hence that $k'\leq n'$.

Comment: When $n$ is odd you also obtain $n$ such pairs when the points form a regular $n$-gon.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: which makes the Reuleaux Triangle claim false, right? For instance, a regular pentagon with diameter $d$ doesn't fit inside such a triangle.

Comment: @TonyK Good catch, I oversimplified the situation a bit much. The same idea still works though.

Comment: And the same refutation, surely?

Comment: @TonyK Presumably you just take the region that is the intersection of the $n$ discs of radius $d$ centred on the points. This is bounded by some number of circular arcs, (not necessarily just 3).

Comment: @TonyK No; take three circles of radius $d$ centered at any three distinct vertices.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are claiming here. For instance, it is not the case that for any two points $u,v$, either $u$ or $v$ must be one of your three vertices.

Comment: @TonyK No, but for any vertex $u$ all points are contained in the circle of radius $d$ centered at $u$. Take a vertex $u$ and two vertices at distance $d$ from $u$ (if such a configuration doesn't exist you're done very quickly), and take the circles centered at these vertices. The intersection of the three circles yields the region I described in my earlier answer that contains all vertices. Either way, I have rewritten my answer to be much more explicit, and hopefully correct this time.